# position a DIV in a specific coordinates Javascript with animaition

Tags: html, position

I want to position a DIV in a specific coordinates ? How can I do that using Javascript ? with animaition

i didnt find it at nowhere

Comment: Maybe you could use jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
document.getElementById('yourDivID').style.position="positionType";
document.getElementById('yourDivID').style.left = leftPos + "px";
document.getElementById('yourDivID').style.top = rightPos + "px";
```

where position type can be fixed, realtive, etc. (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
leftPos and rightPos are the positions where you want to place your div